# decreasing capacity of channel

Tags: stochastic-processes, information-theory

I have a question regarding the capacity of a channel

Consider a channel given by the transition probabilities $p(y|x)$ with capacity $C$.
Now a friendly statistician offers to preprocess the output for you by applying a function
$g$, giving $\bar{y} = g(y)$.
Show that his strategy can only decrease the capacity of the channel, and under which conditions on $g$ is the capacity strictly decreased?

This is my answer for the 1st part.

Since $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow \bar{Y}$. We can apply the data processing inequality,
$I(X;Y)\ge I(X;\bar{Y})$.
Let $\bar{p}(x)$ be the distribution maximising $I(X;\bar{Y})$, then 
$$C=\max_{p(x)}I(X;Y)\geq I(X;Y)_{p(x)=\bar{p}(x)}\geq I(X;\bar{Y})_{p(x)=\bar{p}(x)}=\max_{p(x)}I(X;\bar{Y})=\bar{C}$$ Hence the capacity can never increase the capacity of the channel.

However, how do I do the second part? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Intuitively, what would be your guess?

Comment: I have no intuition haha @JonathanY.

Comment: Surely, if our 'helpful' statistician can undo his contribution, then not all is lost... But need he always be able to do so?

Comment: I don't really get what you mean @JonathanY.

Comment: First show that if $g$ is invertible then the capacity doesn't decrease. Then generalize to cases where $g$ isn't necessarily invertible.